# FPS reduction when resuming the activity

Tags: java, android

I tried making my first android app. It works well but strangely when I pause then resume the main activity (basically when showing the settings menu) the application FPS decrease a lot, and I've no clue why.

Here is my structure:
DrawView is a class implementing the View class with an "update" method which does the stuff at each frame (calculating and drawing).
The main activity create a DrawView (as content view) and with a Handler and a Runnable requests it to refresh every 10ms.

Here is the (simplified) code of Main.java:

```java
public class Main extends Activity {
    DrawView drawView;
    private Handler myHandler;
    private Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            drawView.update();
            myHandler.postDelayed(this, 10);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawView = new DrawView(this);
        setContentView(drawView);
        myHandler = new Handler();
        myHandler.post(myRunnable);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(myHandler != null) myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(myHandler != null) myHandler.post(myRunnable);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.menu_close:
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.menu_settings:
            Intent settingsActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Preferences.class);
            startActivity(settingsActivity);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

By implementing a FPS counter in the DrawView.update method, I noticed that the FPS drop from 100+ at the begining to a ceiling of 60 after opening then closing the preferences Activity.

I don't understand where is my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple: you post your `Runnable` object twice (in `onCreate` and `onResume` methods) and `DrawView.update()` actually will be called more often than once per 10 ms.

When `Activity` is paused you call `myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable)` and it removes **BOTH** previously added objects. After `Activity` is resumed you post the `Runnable` again but only once (because 'onCreate' is not called).

Comment: Oh thanks, it seems obvious now. I didn't know OnResume was called at the beginning of the activity.